# Cannot convert value of type '(Int, Bool, Int)' to specified type '(Int, String?, String?)'

Tags: swift, task

I have started to explore Swift and I got a task from a lesson:

```
You are given a tuple and it has 3 parameters:
StatusCode(Int), Message(Optional String), ErrorMessage(Optional String);

In case if the StatusCode is in a range [200...300] then you have to print the Message,
otherwise you have to print the ErrorMessage.
```

The main idea in the task is that in case if any of last 2 parameters contains not a string then 
it has to contain `nil` because of the Optional String but in my case I get en error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Int, Bool, Int)' to specified type '(Int, String?, String?)'
```

Here is what I did:

```
let tupleResponse : (Int, String?, String?) = (200, true, 567)
let (StatusCode, Message, ErrorMessage) = tupleResponse

if tupleResponse.0 >= 200 && tupleResponse.0 <= 300 {
    if let checkStr1 = tupleResponse.1 {
        tupleResponse.1!
    } else {
        print("Message is nil")
    }
} else {
    if let checkStr2 = tupleResponse.2 {
        tupleResponse.2!
    } else {
        print("Error Message is nil")
    }
}
```

I was expecting that in case of "not string" data type it will make it `nil`, 
however it gives me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your checks and make it a little simpler.

```
let tupleResponse : (statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?) = (200, "true", "567")
// Check and unwrap an error message, check invalid status code
if let errorMessage = tupleResponse.errorMessage, !(200...300).contains(tupleResponse.statusCode){
    print(errorMessage)
}
// Check for valid status code, check and unwrap the message
else if 200...300 ~= tupleResponse.statusCode, let message = tupleResponse.message {
    print(message)
} else { // This should not happen since the above 2 cases check for both described scenarios.
    print("unexpected responses")
}
```

In your code "true, 567" are of invalid types, if you want to send any type.

```
let tupleResponse : (statusCode: Int, message: Any?, errorMessage: Any?) = (200, true, 567)
if let errorMessage = tupleResponse.errorMessage as? String, !(200...300).contains(tupleResponse.statusCode){
    print(errorMessage)
}
else if 200...300 ~= tupleResponse.statusCode, let message = tupleResponse.message as? String{
    print(message)
} else {
    print("unexpected responses")
}
```

But here you will get "unexpected response" because the types don't match with what you expect.

```
let tupleResponse : (statusCode: Int, message: Any?, errorMessage: Any?) = (200, "true", "567")
if let errorMessage = tupleResponse.errorMessage as? String, !(200...300).contains(tupleResponse.statusCode){
    print(errorMessage)
}
else if 200...300 ~= tupleResponse.statusCode, let message = tupleResponse.message as? String{
    print(message)
} else {
    print("unexpected responses")
}
```